# Edit image class (css class) inside contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, image, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I'm developing an very simple WYSIWYG and want to edit images inside editor. Which is the best way in pure JavaScript to modify image class name.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/q/195951/1121982 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) method, or set the [`.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className) property.

```
el.setAttribute('class', 'myClass');
el.className = 'myClass';
```